# Extract maximum pixel value vertex from a raster for a given grid cell without altering the position of the source location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, point-in-polygon, vertices, pixel

I have a 0.5 X 0.5 metre resolution raster. I would like to extract the maximum value points from the raster for every 2 metre square cell. And the extracted points should be in the centre of the source pixel.

[image]

In the shown example, the vertex point 18 should be extracted which is the maximum value within the 2m x 2m. And the position of the vertex point 18 should not be altered. I tried this using resampling tool and then extracting the vertices, but this puts the extracted value in the middle of the 2m x 2m cell.

Comment: Make vector polygon grid 2x2 m and use grass statistic plugin. Check min, max options.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with 'ReadAsArray' method of Python **GDAL** module by using a 4x4 "window" and storing maximum points for each window in a memory layer. For testing my approach, I created a raster of resolution 0.5x0.5, with 20x20 (rows,columns) and values between 1 and 1000 for avoiding repeated values.

My code is as follows; where **print** lines were used for corroborating that code works as expected (so, them could be eliminated).

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
filename = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test_0_5_0_5_clip.tif"
dataset = gdal.Open(filename)
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

xOrigin = transform[0]
yOrigin = transform[3]
pixelWidth = transform[1]
pixelHeight = -transform[5]

cols = dataset.RasterXSize
rows = dataset.RasterYSize

nb = 4

idxs = []

for i in range(0, rows, nb):
    for j in range(0, cols, nb):
        data = band.ReadAsArray(j, i, nb, nb)
        print (data)
        max = np.max(data)
        print ("max: ", max)
        print ("indices maximum original matrix")

        try:
            for m, item in enumerate(data):
                for n, element in enumerate(item):
                    if element == max:
                        idxs.append([m + i, n + j])
                        print(m + i, n + j)

        except TypeError:
            print ("there is no matrix")

x0 = xOrigin + pixelWidth/2
y0 = yOrigin - pixelHeight/2

points = []

for item in idxs:
    x = x0 + item[1]*pixelWidth
    y = y0 - item[0]* pixelHeight
    points.append(QgsPointXY(x,y))

wkt = dataset.GetProjection()

crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
crs.createFromWkt(wkt)

epsg = crs.postgisSrid()

uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'point',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(points)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(points[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running above code, I got following result printed in Python Console only for corroboration purpose.

```
[[557 231 752 950]
 [937   3 282 817]
 [171 548 846 977]
 [929 788 445  64]]
max:  977
indices maximum original matrix
2 3
[[240 503   7 417]
 [ 84 691 877   7]
 [762 163 243 556]
 [644 822 484 860]]
max:  877
indices maximum original matrix
1 6
[[ 38 124 342 813]
 [435 548 524  62]
 [286 101 439 690]
 [598  64   6 589]]
max:  813
indices maximum original matrix
0 11
[[773 594 866 548]
 [427 921 883 621]
 [730 262 270 757]
 [464 158 197 969]]
max:  969
indices maximum original matrix
3 15
[[786 997 865 821]
 [166 118 365 254]
 [483 398 212 419]
 [116 349 555 835]]
max:  997
indices maximum original matrix
0 17
[[640 608 836 124]
 [583 300 605 725]
 [888 927 848 377]
 [866 858 101 396]]
max:  927
indices maximum original matrix
6 1
[[161 301 214 915]
 [760 707 844 739]
 [325 645 883 899]
 [120 307 909 711]]
max:  915
indices maximum original matrix
4 7
[[376 232 369 914]
 [454 300 472 453]
 [970 350 651 959]
 [920 102 706 305]]
max:  970
indices maximum original matrix
6 8
[[ 83  45 620 414]
 [553 493 856 315]
 [572 532 872 384]
 [162 176  91 839]]
max:  872
indices maximum original matrix
6 14
[[222 100   6 767]
 [626 286 227 360]
 [ 58 138 392 251]
 [295 870 719 885]]
max:  885
indices maximum original matrix
7 19
[[168 751 925 455]
 [950  27 809 331]
 [290 800 581 509]
 [ 92 400 144 934]]
max:  950
indices maximum original matrix
9 0
[[891 305 267 809]
 [ 19 457 455 554]
 [303 727 537 865]
 [ 66 253  40 740]]
max:  891
indices maximum original matrix
8 4
[[ 67 831 329 703]
 [804 990 563 263]
 [384 761 801 629]
 [849 441 620 479]]
max:  990
indices maximum original matrix
9 9
[[980 912 581 658]
 [375 879 202 317]
 [ 11 691 138 782]
 [548 538 145 217]]
max:  980
indices maximum original matrix
8 12
[[512 486 145 897]
 [ 79 549   7 618]
 [401 378 826 577]
 [944  35 716 875]]
max:  944
indices maximum original matrix
11 16
[[334 815 132  13]
 [103 767 803 610]
 [532 493 457 809]
 [420  11 311 198]]
max:  815
indices maximum original matrix
12 1
[[201 471 685 237]
 [670   8 707 373]
 [  8 580 690 447]
 [630 869   1   7]]
max:  869
indices maximum original matrix
15 5
[[108 490 358 911]
 [669 285 108 640]
 [148 843 546 293]
 [701 563  79 870]]
max:  911
indices maximum original matrix
12 11
[[339 768 761 774]
 [423  30 326 145]
 [ 22  32 270 764]
 [832 512 672 950]]
max:  950
indices maximum original matrix
15 15
[[416 194 733 435]
 [937 868 344 236]
 [343 852 713 597]
 [163 536 378 610]]
max:  937
indices maximum original matrix
13 16
[[ 64 780 655 329]
 [710 583  48 390]
 [256  73 133  96]
 [446 139 587 703]]
max:  780
indices maximum original matrix
16 1
[[522 609 373 742]
 [117 780 443   2]
 [151 755 598  50]
 [891 365 398 589]]
max:  891
indices maximum original matrix
19 4
[[986 237 501 787]
 [237 586 376 773]
 [187 597 884 789]
 [944 770 441 730]]
max:  986
indices maximum original matrix
16 8
[[915 868  32 780]
 [156 528 133  86]
 [707 945 425 766]
 [190   5 142 960]]
max:  960
indices maximum original matrix
19 15
[[942 404 576 803]
 [282 122 496 181]
 [892 781 924  54]
 [ 30 149 168 742]]
max:  942
indices maximum original matrix
16 16
```

In following image can be observed points situated in the center of each pixel where maximum values are (also corroborated with Value Tool QGIS plugin). It was added a red grid (4x4; 2m x 2m) to facilitate the visualization.

[image]